# Debugging .NET 4.5.1 System.Web.dll source with visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, debug-symbols

I am trying to debug using Visual Studio 2013 and want to step into the .NET source, especially the System.Web.dll but it cannot find the correct .pdb file.

I tried the following steps already:

- set up visual studio as the setup guide from microsoft said: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html
- added http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/ as symbol server
- download the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/download.html) directly and set it as symbol directory

The project is a ASP.NET WebForm Project targeting the .NET 4.5.1 Framework
[image: Project Target framework settings]

In the web.config I set the target framework to 4.5.1 aswell

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" enableVersionHeader="false"/>
```

My test machine is running Windows 8.1 and I am using the local IIS server.

When debugging the symbols get loaded, but looking into my symbol directory in FailedLoads shows a lot of symbols failed to load.

> _WINDOWS_Microsoft.Net_assembly_GAC_64_System.Web_v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a_System.Web.txt

with content:

> Not Found

[image: FailedLoads directory]

System.Web.dll is in the [list of Assemblies](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/indexedpdbs.txt) that are supposed to have symbols, but when I want to load them it says it cannot find them.
[image]

How do I debug the .NET System.Web.dll in visual studio 2013

Comment: Donno if this will solve your problem, but i debug into the lib sometimes. I've added the "http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public" to the symbol sources. When working with different projects with different version dependencies, you sometimes have to clear the symbol cache to solve the problem. In Asp.Net projects you also have to clear the temporary compiled assemblies sometimes to get VS'13 to sync correctly.

Comment: @MarvinSmit the website at that link is broken

Comment: Use http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio for the docs of how to set it up in visual studio.